# Looping through content of the current directory

Tags: shell

What is the best way to look inside a directory and determine whether its content are directories or files. Its a homework question.

My homework requires me to write a script that counts the number of directories, files, how many are executable, writeable, and readable.

Comment: You will actually have to do some of the work yourself.

Comment: This question will be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962155/logical-error-in-shell-script-please-help-unix

Comment: Please don't double post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340974/basic-shell-scripting-with-control-structures-counting-the-number-of-directories

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the bourne shell family, take a look at the `-d`, `-x`, `-w`... and I'm guessing `-r` tests.  Look up how a for loop works in bash to see how to iterate over the files... the general idea is

```
for var in directory/*; do
    #stuff with $var
done
```

But there are some particulars relating to spaces in filenames that can make this trickier.

Comment: In this assignment, you will write a shell script that calculates the following information for the contents of a given directory. The directory is to be specified as a single command line argument to your script. You do not need to account for any contents of nested subdirectories -- just the direct contents of the specified directory.

Comment: The total number of directories that are in the given directory (note that these are subdirectories).
The total number of files in the given directory.
The number of items (files/directories) in the current directory that are readable.
The number of items (files/directories) in the current directory that are writable.
The number of items (files/directories) in the current directory that are executable. I tried the code for item in $file
do
if [ -d $file ]
then
  counter=`expr $counter + 1`
fi
  echo "Number of directories    :" $counter

done

Comment: @Andrew K: You have the right idea in your code snippet, just double-check your 'for' and 'if' lines.  Use 'echo' inside the loop and conditional to check and make sure that all of your variables are holding the values that you think they are holding.

Comment: @Andrew: You can avoid posting duplicates of your assignment's instructions by editing them into your original question. If you want to be sure and call an answerer's attention to an update, you can post a comment on their answer saying "Please see my updated question."

Answer (score 0):

Use the -X style operators:

```
[ -d "${item}" ] && echo "${item} is a directory"
```

See the bash man page (search for "CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS") to see the complete list.

Looping through contents of a directory and counting looks like this:

```
dirs=0
writeable=0
for item in /path/to/directory/*; do

    [ -d "${item}" ] && dirs=$(( dirs + 1 ))  # works in bash
    [ -w "${item}" ] && writeable=`expr ${writeable} + 1` # works in bourne shell

    # Other tests

done

echo "Found ${dirs} sub-directories"
echo "Found ${writeable} writeable files"
```

Comment: will write a shell script that calculates the following information for the contents of a given directory. The directory is to be specified as a single command line argument to your script. You do not need to account for any contents of nested subdirectories -- just the direct contents of the specified directory. –

Comment: The total number of directories that are in the given directory (note that these are subdirectories). The total number of files in the given directory. The number of items (files/directories) in the current directory that are readable. The number of items (files/directories) in the current directory that are writable. The number of items (files/directories) in the current directory that are executable. I tried the code for item in $file do if [ -d $file ] then counter=expr $counter + 1 fi echo "Number of directories :" $counter done

Comment: @Andrew K: I've updated to show how to add in bash and bourne shell. But really, if this is a school assignment you should be figuring this out yourself. If you are going to be doing more of shell script assignments, I would suggest reading through the whole bash man page and experimenting with what you learn. It's a tough read and it will take a couple hours but will pay off in the end (not just in school but with the powerful tools you will learn). Or read through this: http://www.linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial